# Finding multiple search results in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have an array that I made that consists of first names. I have a search function that searches through the elements of the array and it works fine. However, for multiple elements of an array, I cannot find out how to print how many results were returned. For example, if "John" in my example is found, which it is, I do not know how to show that there were multiple results found. Someone please help me. I need to get "count" to increase 1 time for each result found. Here is my code:
`

```
import java.util.*;

class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String[] firstName = new String[]{"John", "Thomas", "Samuel", "Chris", "Daniel", "Joey", "David", "Joshua", "Michael", "John"};
       Arrays.sort(firstName);
       System.out.print("Enter a search term: ");
       String name = search.next();

       int i;

       boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
       for (i = 0; i < firstName.length; i++) {
           if (firstName[i] == name) {
                   foundIt = true;

               }
           }


       if (foundIt = true){
            System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " produced " + count + " search results");
       }

       else {
           System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " did not return any results");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: don't use `==` for comparing Strings in Java! This will only return true if both Strings are the same instance, use `equals` for comparing the contents of the String. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 1):

You could change the boolean foundIt to int count, and increment where you set foundIt to true.

So something like:

```
int count = 0;

search:
   for (i = 0; i < firstName.length; i++) {
       if (firstName[i] == name) {
               count++;
       }
   }


   if (count > 0){
        System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " produced " + count + " search results");
   }

   else {
       System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " did not return any results");
   }
```

Comment: Simple, concise and doesn't do anyone's homework for them!  Perfect answer.

Comment: same here: don't use `==` for comparing Strings in Java!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] firstName = {"John", "Thomas", "Samuel", "Chris", "Daniel", "Joey", "David", "Joshua", "Michael", "John"};
    Arrays.sort(firstName);
    System.out.print("Enter a search term: ");
    String name = search.next();

    int count = 0;
    for (String aFirstName : firstName) {
        if (aFirstName.equals(name)) {
            count++;
        }else if(count > 0){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(count > 0){
        System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " produced " + count + " search results");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " did not return any results");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the results to an ArrayList, it's a little easier to understand then. Furthermore you assign the variable in the if statement and you use the `==` operator on strings, you should use `.equals()`.

Another thing that stood out was the label in the code, you should stay away from them, since they require the use of the infamous `break` statement. See Dijkstra's [considered harmful.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful)

This way you can also iterate over the found names afterwards.

See the example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;    
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] firstNames = new String[]{
            "John",
            "Thomas",
            "Samuel",
            "Chris",
            "Daniel",
            "Joey",
            "David",
            "Joshua",
            "Michael",
            "John"};

        Arrays.sort(firstNames);
        System.out.print("Enter a search term: ");
        String name = search.next();

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : firstNames) {
            if (s.equals(name)) {
                results.add(s);
            }
        }


        if (results.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " produced " + results.size() + " search results");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your search term of " + name + " did not return any results");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void searchName(){

Employee[]e=toEmployee();
for(int i=0;i<em.size();i++){
    if(e[i].getName().equals(tfs.getText())){
        tfi.setText(e[i].getId());
        tfn.setText(e[i].getName());
        tfh.setText(e[i].getHour()+"");
        tfr.setText(e[i].getRate()+"");
    }
}
}
```